# Finding polygons of one layer that either fit inside or overlap another specific polygon using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have a layer with the population density of a city, in polygons that represent the city blocks. I also have a layer of arbitrary hexagons. I want to calculate the population that each hexagon has by finding the polygons that overlap each hexagon, iterating on those to find the area that is actually inside the hexagon and multiplying that by the population density.

First, I am trying to count the blocks that intersect a hexagon, just to get this working. But the `QgsSpatialIndex.intersects(geometry)` function returns a null result. This is my code:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

_Layer_hexa = 'Hexagon_Layer'
_Layer_densidad = 'Population_density'

layer_dens = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(_Layer_densidad)[0]
layer_hexa = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(_Layer_hexa)[0]

_DENS_FIELD = 'Dens pob'
_NEW_SUM_FIELD1 = 'Blocks'

# Create new field:
layer_hexa.startEditing()
layer_hexa.dataProvider().addAttributes(
        [QgsField(_NEW_SUM_FIELD1, QVariant.Int),
         ])
layer_hexa.updateFields()

# Feature dictionaries
feature_dict_hexa = {f.id(): f for f in layer_hexa.getFeatures()}
feature_dict_dens = {f.id(): f for f in layer_dens.getFeatures()}

# Build spatial indexes
index_hexa = QgsSpatialIndex()
for f in feature_dict_hexa.values():
    index_hexa.insertFeature(f)

index_dens = QgsSpatialIndex()
for f in feature_dict_dens.values():
    index_dens.insertFeature(f)

# Iterate the hexagons:
c=0
mzas = 0
for f in feature_dict_hexa.values():

    # Get the hexagon geometry
    geom = f.geometry()
    # Find all features that intersect the bounding box of the current feature.
    # We use spatial index to find the features intersecting the bounding box
    # of the current feature. This will narrow down the features that we need
    # to check neighboring features.

# This is where it returns null------------------------------------------------------------
    intersecting_ids_dens = index_dens.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #Initialize the sum:
    mzas = 0
    # Iterate on the intersections:
    for intersecting_id in intersecting_ids_dens:
        #Find the feature in the dictionary
        intersecting_f = feature_dict_dens[intersecting_id]

        # Check that the geometries actually intersect:
        if not intersecting_f.geometry().disjoint(geom):
            mzas += 1

    f[_NEW_SUM_FIELD1] = mzas
    c += 1
    # Updateamos la layer con este cambio
    layer_hexa.updateFeature(f)

layer_hexa.commitChanges()
print('Processing complete.')
```

I have read the `QgsSpatialIndex` documentation but am still at a loss as to why it isn't working. While this gets posted I will try to merge the hexagon and density layer and see if this works using only one layer, but I would still like to understand why the code above doesn't work.

I am basing my code around this code by Ujaval Gandhi for finding neighboring polygons: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/find_neighbor_polygons.html

Comment: I am not sure if this should be an edit on the question, a comment or an answer itself. The issue seems to be that the density layer uses a CRS that is not defined in QGIS and that's different from the hexagon layer. The layer is rendered correctly but when examining the geometry of its features in PyQGIS it reads it as a different CRS and the polygon ends up being quite different than the rendered one (i.e. displaced to a far away location). I will see if I can fix the CRS of the layer and I will update this with more information if that works.